# Can we created an API that accepts multipart/mixed type requests and store the request data in CSV on IICS

Tags: curl, iics

I need to create an API that accepts multipart mixed type of requests and a process to store the data in CSV. I didn't find any option that accepts multipart mixed type of requests. I tried building an API on IICS for accepting the Multipart mixed type data but it is not accepting and storing the data on a file. I have created a process and exposed it as an API to store the coming post request data using file writer, but it is not helping.